# I am plotting columns in a table against each other. If a blank cell is included my axes values suddenly make no sense... Screenshots inside

Tags: excel

This is a weird one. I have a column A with lets say 50 values and column B with 100 values. Column A is comprised of 50 numbers and the rest of the cells contain "". When I plot A & B I want only the 50 data points that are present in both series. If I do this by selecting the actual data, my [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAgf4.png) comes out fine.

However, if I select the entire column, the x axis suddenly jumps from 9.9 to 100. Why? There are no values that are 100 and the data points appear to be equally stretched out (it's not just 1 cell messing this up - the whole data series gets dialated). Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRjy2.png) if I include even a single line with a blank cell.

Comment: Likely you're looking at two different chart types - first is scatter plot but the second is not (so the x axis is the the *index number* of each point rather than the value)

Comment: You're on to something! It appears that Excel will plot the values of a series if _every_ value is an integer.

With a series containing purely data, things [work out well](http://i.imgur.com/MJrKxCz.png). However, if a single value is a non-integer, Excel resorts to [plotting index values](http://i.imgur.com/viEJ50Y.png).

Not that in both example I am using a scatter. Is there a way to prevent Excel from doing this? My data is blank for certain conditions and I necessarily do not want it plotted. However, I would like to keep the data range for plotting as the entire column for ease.

Comment: You could try: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/08/06/change-the-default-chart-type-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

try these 3 steps.
 1. With table selected click 'Select Data' under 'Chart Tools/Design'
 2. Click 'Hidden and Empty Cells'
 3. Click Connect data points with line

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried it and it didn't work, unfortunately. The graph remains unchanged.